# Pass longitude and latitude from CLLocationManager to URL?

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager

i'm trying to pass my latitude and longitude to my url params but is returning Nil, but when i print within the delegate it returns the longitude and latitude and i can't seem to find the issue, i've tried many different ways and nothing seems to work

this are the variable where i store my latitude and longitude

`var lat: Double!
 var long: Double!`

this is my delegate

```
func locationManager(_ manager:CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]){

    currentLocation = manager.location!.coordinate

    let locValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = currentLocation!

    self.long = locValue.longitude
    self.lat = locValue.latitude

    print(lat)
    print(long)

}
```

and here pass them to variables i'm using in my URL parameters but they return nil and i don't understand why

```
let userLat = String(describing: lat)
let userLong = String(describing: long)
```

Thank You

Comment: Where exactly are you declaring `lat`and `long`? And where are you trying to get their values? Did you assign your delegate to the CLLocationManager instance?

Comment: after my class, and i did assign its delegate on the view did load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

**Swift 3**

```
func locationManager(_ manager:CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]){

    if let last = locations.last {
        sendLocation(last.coordinate)
    }

}

func sendLocation(_ coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    let userLat = NSString(format: "%f", coordinate.latitude) as String
    let userLong = NSString(format: "%f", coordinate.longitude) as String

    // Run API Call....
}
```

Comment: i tried that but didn't work, for some reason the values aren't coming out of the delegate, if i print lat outside the delegate it retuns nil

Comment: got it working, thank you so much man really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

I think the Joseph K's answer is not correct. It rounds off the values of the latitude and longitude. It will be something like the code below.

```
let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(exactly: 35.6535425)!, longitude: CLLocationDegrees(exactly: 139.7047917)!)

let latitude = coordinate.latitude // 35.6535425
let longitude = coordinate.longitude // 139.7047917

let latitudeString = NSString(format: "%f", latitude) as String // "35.653543"
let longitudeString = NSString(format: "%f", longitude) as String // "139.704792"
```

So the correct and simpler code is:

**Swift 3**

```
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        guard let coordinate = locations.last?.coordinate else { return }

        let latitude = "\(coordinate.latitude)"
        let longitude = "\(coordinate.longitude)"

        // Do whatever you want to make a URL.
    }
```